# Android Studio - Debugging: Jump to next break point?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I have been searching, how to jump to next break point in **Android Studio** while debugging your application.

I have been using `F8` in eclipse to do the same thing but could not find anything in **Android Studio**.

Any idea, where it is?

Comment: You can change the keymap to eclipse style in settings -> keymap. This way you have all your keys like in eclipse and can use `F8` for continue. Otherwise check the keymap for the key.

Comment: F9 is the default Resume Program

Answer (score 25):

Use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> for next break point.

Comment: for mac OS, you need `fn+option+F9`

Answer (score 17):

In android studio, in debug mode, choose the menu "run", click "Resume Program", it would go to the next breakpoint.

Comment: This one really helped me for Android Studio 4.0

Comment: Thanks you very much. It helpmed me also.

Answer (score 9):

Use F9 to move to next breakpoint in Studio, the equivalent of F8 in Eclipse

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the eclipse shortcuts to debug in android studio,

just you need to change the keymap settings,

File > settings > keyMap > Choose eclipse and apply .!

Answer (score 4):

You can easily see all keys when you do mouseover as seen below-

[image]

Comment: this is step by step , i want jump from on breakpoint to next breakpoint.

Comment: Check the adjacent buttons to the highlighted one. Its there. Check the arrow one.

Answer (score 3):

**This question has already been answered, but this also might be helpful for future readers:**

Just like it was mentioned already, you can jump to the next breakpoint using `ALT + F9` on windows or `fn + shift + command + F9` on mac. You can also customize the keyboard shortcut that you would like to use in order to make it convenient (For instance: making debugging with the `F8` key if you want to). Here is how to do it:

Android Studio--> Preferences--> Keymap--> type in the search bar "breakpoint"--> double click the shortcut you want to edit--> select "add keyboard shortcut" and then put what is convenient for you" (make sure it is not a duplicate). **Done !** [image]

Answer (score 2):

Default key for `Resume` when debugging in Android Studio is <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Command to jump to next break point in Android studio (2.3.3) debugging is

- `F9` on Linux(Ubuntu)
- `Alt + F9` on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this what you really wants but I think it is what you are looking for:

**Debug your app with breakpoints**

After you set breakpoints in your code, click **Rerun**  to start the app again. When a breakpoint is hit, Android Studio pauses the app and highlights the breakpoint in the source code. The Debug tool window lets you examine variables and control the execution step by step:

To examine the object tree for a variable, expand it in the Variables view. If the Variables view is not visible, click Restore Variables View  .
To evaluate an expression at the current execution point, click Evaluate Expression .
To advance to the next line in the code (without entering a method), click Step Over .
To advance to the first line inside a method call, click Step Into .
To advance to the next line outside the current method, click Step Out .
To continue running the app normally, click Resume Program .

If this doesn't help you, refer to the official documentation and see if this can help you, I got that information from the official documentation:

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

For me (macOs Sierra) it's cmd + alt + R.

Answer (score 0):

**option+command+R** will jump to the next breakpoint on mac.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS, the default shortcut is **F9** or **Command** + **Option** + **R**. But these shortcuts are pretty hard to reach with your fingers, especially on a MacBook without touchbar. My personal preference is **Option** + **.**, because the key combination is closer and more convenience. Just select **Add keyboard shortcut** to **Resume program** keymap, and type any shortcut you want:

[image]